# Are branches actually equal to their last commits in git?

Tags: git

I read about "detached head" in git and it happens when someone checks out to a "commit" instead of a "branch".

The curios part for me (which I couldn't verify through man pages or Google) is whether a branch is indeed internally a reference to its last commit? (Otherwise, I think maybe checkout command could disallow the occurrence of a detached head..., but it doesn't.)

In case that the above guess is correct, can we say all branches are references to the commits at the tip of them?

(Basically, this doubt grew in me when I read these two separate comments from two people:

1. HEAD is a ref (reference) to the currently **checked out commit**.
2. **checkout to a branch** not to a commit!

So I thought maybe person#2 is suggesting to use branches for checking out since it guarantees moving the HEAD to a "tip commit").

Comment: Did you try checking out a commit that was also the tip of a branch? What happened?

Comment: @jonrsharpe You mean it's still a detached HEAD...! Right? That's a good thing to notice...

Comment: I'd recommend reviewing some of the many existing resources, e.g. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is

Comment: @jonrsharpe So why is it allowed that we can checkout to commits at all? (Thanks for the link)

Comment: Why *wouldn't* that be allowed? How else would you go back to revisions that weren't the tips of branches?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, branch is just a reference to a commit that gets updated once you make a new commit in its checkout. You can even create branches manually.

(just preparing a repo with two commits)

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/che/foo/.git/
$ touch bar
$ git add bar
$ git commit -minitial
[master (root-commit) 5d512c6] initial
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 bar
$ touch second
$ git add second 
$ git commit -msecond_commit
[master 5aebe72] second_commit
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 second
$ git log --format='%H %s'
5aebe72d3f6cd72c3236021319d8ea43eae899fe second_commit
5d512c6fcec86f02d69a7b4f5f177ec1a6ecb32e initial
```

(now make a new file in `.git/refs/heads`, which is one of the places where git keeps branches)

```
$ echo 5d512c6fcec86f02d69a7b4f5f177ec1a6ecb32e > .git/refs/heads/old
$ git branch
* master
old
```

(or you can look in the files, there are commit hashes, nothing else)

```
$ fgrep '' .git/refs/heads/*
.git/refs/heads/master:5aebe72d3f6cd72c3236021319d8ea43eae899fe
.git/refs/heads/old:5d512c6fcec86f02d69a7b4f5f177ec1a6ecb32e
```

There are other kinds of references (remote branches and tags), and they can also be stored in compressed files, so these file operations will not always work, but you can inspect and mess with refs using `git show-ref` and `git update-ref`.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is a great answer and I can review many commands and concepts together, but someone has asked something in the comments below my question that I couldn't answer to. Even if we checkout to the tip of a branch, Git tells us that we're in a detached head..., so if branch is just a reference to a commit, how come git can distinguish the two states? (Maybe it's a reference with some added information?!) (Thanks once again).

Comment: `git` distinguishes *detached HEAD* from checked out branch by the content of `.git/HEAD` file: when a branch is checked out the file contains the name of the branch (`master`, for example) while in detached HEAD mode the file contains SHA-1 hash id of the commit.

Comment: @phd Interesting! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The way it works is that HEAD is actually the contents of the file .git/HEAD. Checking out a branch results in .git/HEAD containing the branch name (the full ref). The branch name then evaluates to a path in the .git directory which contains a hash. So when you make a new commit on that branch, only the ref changes, to the latest commit hash. .git/HEAD does not need to change.

When you check out a commit hash directly, .git/HEAD just contains the commit hash. For example, if you check out the commit hash representing the last commit in *master*, it is more or less the same as checking out *master*.

The only difference is that committing to *master* or pulling updates from a public repository won't change what you're checked out to, and committing from that state won't change the *master* branch.

An example session demonstrating some of these points:

```
util$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
util$ cat .git/refs/heads/master
3e213b3d373a9d157426db2ae40e0b5b8ba9c3b2
util$ git checkout 3e21
Note: checking out '3e21'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 3e21 edit_with_editor() takes a line kwarg
util$ cat .git/HEAD
3e213b3d373a9d157426db2ae40e0b5b8ba9c3b2
```

So 'master' does evaluate to a commit hash, just indirectly:

```
util$ git rev-parse master
3e213b3d373a9d157426db2ae40e0b5b8ba9c3b2
```

If I make a commit in this state, it changes HEAD but not master:

```
util$ echo Example change >> README
util$ git commit -a -m "example commit in detached head state"
[detached HEAD 45d4] example commit in detached head state
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 README
util$ cat .git/HEAD
45d4b4f7816dc7626be6f7166f7cf972dc18a9d7
util$ git rev-parse master
3e213b3d373a9d157426db2ae40e0b5b8ba9c3b2
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great answer! Can you explain the second paragraph a bit more? (I have problem with the English used not the technical terms, I'm not a native English speaker)

Comment: Sure, I just edited it to make some things clear. I split up the second paragraph and changed the wording. I hope that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: (I appreciate it.) I think(guess) the reason(or at least one of the reasons) that in the detached head state, commits can no longer change what we have checked out to is that a hash alone inside .git/HEAD does not determine any branch since more than one branches at once could have that commit as their last commit. (BTW, I literally don't know which answer to choose as accepted both are very good :D)

Comment: That's true but just to clarify, committing will still change what you're checked out to - it will just be a new commit hash (See my last paragraph). But if you ever check out a branch or a different hash, it might be difficult to find your old work. Eventually, it will actually be deleted (pruned).